# Is it possible to redirect to HTTP error pages using PHP instead of .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've been having some trouble with my .htaccess file lately (my entire site goes down, replaced by a 500 error, whenever I put the file to my server). I've been wondering if it's possible to completely replace the error page functionality of the .htaccess file using PHP. Additionally, if someone could help me out with my .htaccess issue, that would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: I'm not sure about replacing the error reporting functionality completely, but I do know you can specify custom php error pages through the htaccess. As for the problem with your htaccess file itself, I had the same issue a short while ago. Apparently some syntax errors will cause this behavior. My host kept overwriting my htaccess files every time I tried to upload because of a small oversight in syntax.

Comment: Which hosting service are you using?

Comment: I'm with 1and1, but the .htaccess file worked previously; in fact, I had this problem before, and it seemed to resolve itself. Now, I've tried to restore the file from a backup from a few hours ago, before the problem arose; to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it's possible using by php header function.for redirecting to 404 error page add this code top of your script.

```
<?php
header("Location:error.php");
?>
```

or using this code to show 404 error page:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Comment: How will you put this code on a page which does not exist. That's what a 404 is.